# Windows 8 bluetooth audio choppy when there is network activity

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I brought a generic bluetooth dongle for my pc and a Rapoo H6060 Bluetooth headset. After pairing I connected the headset to PC and that's fine.

The issue is when I'm listen to music on the bluetooth headset, the sound is choppy when I'm download or even browsing.  I stopped the download and everything ran pretty smooth.

is that a issue with my dongle? (it's a cheap generic one which doesn't provide any drivers) or it might be the pc it self?

i got a core i7 930, 6gb of ram (ram get 40 utilization most time) samsung 840 ssd and a 1.5TB hdd from seagate.

Comment: I realize it may be issue with wifi 2.4 and bluetooth interference, but it's not an issue with iphone, so is this a bluetooth dongle issue?